# Extracting rows in a Dataframe having a common number with another dataframe column and joining both rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have a df1 something like 
[image: df1]

and df2 as [image: df2]

need to create a df that uses a uniquenumber in df1 and sees if that occurs in df2 and then joins the row from df1 like below result df3
[image: df3]

I have tried concat like 
import pandas as pd

`df1 = pd.read_excel('example_for_df1_excl.xlsx', sheet_name='actual').drop_duplicates()`

`df2 = pd.read_excel('example_for_df2_excl.xlsx', sheet_name='sheet1').drop_duplicates()`

`df3 = df1[['value','date','uniquenum1']]`
`df4 = df2[['value','date','uniquenum2']]`
`df5=pd.concat([df3,df4]).drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)`
`df6=df_concat[df_concat['value'].notna()]`

and also for loop like:

`for i, row in df3.iterrows():`
     `if row ['value'] == df2['valuedf2']:`

but just cant seem to get the results I want, Help and Ideas much appreciated , thanks

Comment: in df1 column uniquenum1...uniquenum10 the number is compared on df2 coulmn uniquennmm and then the row from df1 is joined to that row in df2 where the same uniquenum appeas

Answer (score 0):

Use a join operation.

```
df3 = pd.merge(
    left=df1,
    right=df2,
    left_on='uniquenumber',
    right_on='uniquenum2',
    how='both' # You can also use 'left' or 'right' here. If you use 'left', all values in the first dataframe are kept. Similar with 'right' but for the second dataframe.
)
```